# Python-daemon doesn't kill its kids

Tags: python, daemon, multiprocessing, children, zombie-process

When using [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/), I'm creating subprocesses likeso:

```
import multiprocessing

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
   def __init__(self, queue):
      self.queue = queue # we wait for things from this in Worker.run()

   ...

q = multiprocessing.Queue()

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    for i in xrange(3):
       Worker(q)

    while True: # let the Workers do their thing
       q.put(_something_we_wait_for())
```

When I kill the parent daemonic process (i.e. not a Worker) with a Ctrl-C or SIGTERM, etc., the children don't die. How does one kill the kids?

My first thought is to use [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit) to kill all the workers, likeso:

```
 with daemon.DaemonContext():
    workers = list()
    for i in xrange(3):
       workers.append(Worker(q))

    @atexit.register
    def kill_the_children():
        for w in workers:
            w.terminate()

    while True: # let the Workers do their thing
       q.put(_something_we_wait_for())
```

However, the children of daemons are tricky things to handle, and I'd be obliged for thoughts and input on how this ought to be done.

Thank you.

Comment: Killing your kids does seem like a "daemonic" thing to do...

Comment: Definitely. This daemon is *not* up to spec.

Comment: Isn't this Python? You can't just do `from evil import infanticide` or something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your options are a bit limited. If doing `self.daemon = True` in the constructor for the `Worker` class does not solve your problem and trying to catch signals in the Parent (ie, `SIGTERM, SIGINT`) doesn't work, you may have to try the opposite solution - instead of having the parent kill the children, you can have the children commit suicide when the parent dies.

The first step is to give the constructor to `Worker` the `PID` of the parent process (you can do this with `os.getpid()`). Then, instead of just doing `self.queue.get()` in the worker loop, do something like this:

```
waiting = True
while waiting:
    # see if Parent is at home
    if os.getppid() != self.parentPID:
        # woe is me! My Parent has died!
        sys.exit() # or whatever you want to do to quit the Worker process
    try:
        # I picked the timeout randomly; use what works
        data = self.queue.get(block=False, timeout=0.1)
        waiting = False
    except queue.Queue.Empty:
        continue # try again
# now do stuff with data
```

The solution above checks to see if the parent PID is different than what it originally was (that is, if the child process was adopted by `init` or `lauchd` because the parent died) - see [reference](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg55718.html). However, if that doesn't work for some reason you can replace it with the following function (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/check-if-pid-is-not-in-use-in-python)):

```
def parentIsAlive(self):
    try:
        # try to call Parent
        os.kill(self.parentPID, 0)
    except OSError:
        # *beeep* oh no! The phone's disconnected!
        return False
    else:
        # *ring* Hi mom!
        return True
```

Now, when the Parent dies (for whatever reason), the child Workers will spontaneously drop like flies - just as you wanted, you daemon! `:-D`

Comment: I really would like to give you more than 1 point for this answer :D

Comment: isn't this busy-waiting since the queue.get is not blocking anymore? IMO it would be better to insert a special object (like None) in the queue with atexit in the main thread and let the children sys.exit() if they get the None object.

Answer (score 4):

You should store the parent pid when the child is first created (let's say in `self.myppid`) and when `self.myppid` is diferent from `getppid()` means that the parent died.

To avoid checking if the parent has changed over and over again, you can use `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` that is described [in the signals documentation](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-5.html).

> 5.8 The Linux "parent death" signal
>
> For each process there is a variable pdeath_signal, that is
> initialized to 0 after fork() or clone(). It gives the signal that the
> process should get when its parent dies.

In this case, you want your process to die, you can just set it to a `SIGHUP`, like this:

```
prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP);
```

Comment: Hmm, that actually *might* work - `os.getppid()` should return 1 if the parent dies (ie, `init` (for Linux) or `launchd` (for Mac OS X) adopts the children).

Answer (score 2):

Atexit won't do the trick -- it only gets run on successful non-signal termination -- see the note near the top of the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html). You need to set up signal handling via one of two means.

The easier-sounding option: set the daemon flag on your worker processes, per http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions

Somewhat harder-sounding option: [PEP-3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) seems to imply there is a built-in way to hook program cleanup needs in python-daemon.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Incidentally, a related question I've posted is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546276/python-process-wont-call-atexit -- it covers some of these topics. I'd like to know the pattern for ensuring that children get killed (or don't become zombies) - I guess the multiprocessing daemon flag will make a difference - does it cover all cases? What cases?