# Python Process won't call atexit

Tags: python, multiprocessing, terminate, atexit

I'm trying to use `atexit` in a `Process`, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Here's some example code:

```
import time
import atexit
import logging
import multiprocessing

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class W(multiprocessing.Process):
    def run(self):
        logging.debug("%s Started" % self.name)

        @atexit.register
        def log_terminate():
             # ever called?
             logging.debug("%s Terminated!" % self.name)

        while True:
            time.sleep(10)

@atexit.register
def log_exit():
    logging.debug("Main process terminated")

logging.debug("Main process started")

a = W()
b = W()
a.start()
b.start()
time.sleep(1)
a.terminate()
b.terminate()
```

The output of this code is:

```
DEBUG:root:Main process started
DEBUG:root:W-1 Started
DEBUG:root:W-2 Started
DEBUG:root:Main process terminated
```

I would expect that the `W.run.log_terminate()` would be called when `a.terminate()` and `b.terminate()` are called, and the output to be something likeso (emphasis added)!:

```
DEBUG:root:Main process started
DEBUG:root:W-1 Started
DEBUG:root:W-2 Started
DEBUG:root:W-1 Terminated!
DEBUG:root:W-2 Terminated!
DEBUG:root:Main process terminated
```

Why isn't this working, and is there a better way to log a message (from the `Process` context) when a `Process` is terminated?

Thank you for your input - it's much appreciated.

## Solution

**EDIT:**  Based on solution suggested by Alex Martelli, the following works as expected:

```
import sys
import time
import atexit
import signal
import logging
import multiprocessing

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class W(multiprocessing.Process):
    def run(self):
        logging.debug("%s Started" % self.name)

        def log_terminate(num, frame):
             logging.debug("%s Terminated" % self.name)
             sys.exit()
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, log_terminate)
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)

@atexit.register
def log_exit():
    logging.debug("Main process terminated")

logging.debug("Main process started")
a = W()
b = W()
a.start()
b.start()
time.sleep(1)
a.terminate()
b.terminate()
```

It's worthwhile to note the following comment in the `atexit` documentation:

> Note: the functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.

Comment: A possible workaround is to make use of undocumented `multiprocessing.util.Finalize` class, see the blog post for details: [Guaranteed Finalization Without Context Manager](https://zpz.github.io/blog/guaranteed-finalization-without-context-manager/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=terminate#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) say,

> On Unix this is done using the SIGTERM
>   signal; on Windows TerminateProcess()
>   is used. Note that exit handlers and
>   finally clauses, etc., will not be
>   executed.

If you're on Unix, you should be able intercept `SIGTERM` with [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html?highlight=signal#module-signal), and perform whatever "termination activities" you need; however, I don't know of a cross-platform solution.