# python kill parent process but child process left

Tags: python, subprocess

While I try to kill a python process, the child process started via `os.system` won't be terminated at the same time.

[Killing child process when parent crashes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128410/killing-child-process-when-parent-crashes-in-python) and 
[Python Process won't call atexit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546276/python-process-wont-call-atexit)
(atexit looks like not work with signal)

Does that mean I need to handle this situation by myself? If so, what is the preferred way to do so?

```
> python main.py
> ps
4792 ttys002    0:00.03 python run.py
4793 ttys002    0:00.03 python loop.py 
> kill -15 4792
> ps 
4793 ttys002    0:00.03 python loop.py
```

Sample Code:

main.py

```
import os
os.system('python loop.py')
```

loop.py

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1000)
```

## UPDATE1

I did some experiment, and find out a workable version but still confuse about the logic.

```
import os
import sys
import signal
import subprocess


def sigterm_handler(_signo, _stack_frame):
    # it raises SystemExit(0):
    print 'go die'
    sys.exit(0)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

try:
    # os.system('python loop.py') 
    # use os.system won't work, it will even ignore the SIGTERM entirely for some reason 
    subprocess.call(['python', 'loop.py'])
except:
    os.killpg(0, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: The problem here is probably because you're killing it with the `SIGKILL` signal (-9). What it means is that it's going to kill the process without calling any other signal handler because `SIGKILL` can't be trapped. You should use `SIGTERM` instead and use `SIGKILL` when all else fail.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix sorry it's actually a typo. I kill the process with SIGTERM.

Comment: You may want to read the stuff about signals here: https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Comment: @lucemia: my answer had inprecise statement. Though it doesn't change the code example. See [the update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34027738/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks, your answer really useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill -15 4792` sends `SIGTERM` to `run.py` in your example -- it sends nothing to `loop.py` (or its parent shell). `SIGTERM` is not propagated to other processes in the process tree by default.

`os.system('python loop.py')` starts at least **two** processes the shell and `python` process. You don't need it; use `subprocess.check_call()`, to run a single child process without the implicit shell. btw, if your [subprocess is a Python script; consider importing it and running corresponding functions instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279).

`os.killpg(0, SIGKILL)` sends `SIGKILL` signal to the current process group. <strike>A shell creates a new process group (a job) for each pipeline and therefore the `os.killpg()` in the parent has no effect on the child</strike> (see the update). See [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    p = subprocess.Popen([executable, 'loop'])
except EnvironmentError as e: # 
    sys.exit('failed to start %r, reason: %s' % (executable, e))
else:
    try: # wait for the child process to finish
        p.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # on Ctrl+C (SIGINT)
        #NOTE: the shell sends SIGINT (on CtrL+C) to the executable itself if
        #  the child process is in the same foreground process group as its parent 
        sys.exit("interrupted")
```

### Update

It seems `os.system(cmd)` doesn't create a new process group for `cmd`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getpgrp()
16180
>>> import sys
>>> cmd = sys.executable + ' -c "import os; print(os.getpgrp())"'
>>> os.system(cmd) #!!! same process group
16180
0
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex
>>> subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(cmd))
16180
0
>>> subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
16180
0
>>> subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp) #!!! new
18644
0
```

and therefore `os.system(cmd)` in your example should be killed by the `os.killpg()` call.

Though if I run it in bash; it does create a new process group for each pipeline:

```
$ python -c "import os; print(os.getpgrp())"
25225
$ python -c "import os; print(os.getpgrp())"
25248
```