# Python setup with online updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-update, esky

I developed a software using python on my back-end. We just installed on a couple clients but i'm already seeing the problem with version updates. Today, a manually install new versions on the clients desktops, but i made some research and discovery some tools like, Esky, PyInstaller + PyUpdater, etc... My question is: what is the best way to install and update softwares on python? I'm lookin for a 
easyest and best solution for this problems. Do we hame some "right" way  to do it?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932389/how-to-remotely-update-python-applications) might be an interesting read.

Comment: Gabriel Thanks for the reply, this post was dated from 2011, this is still the best way to do it?

Comment: I wouldn't know if it is the **best** way, since my knowledge on this subject is limited. **Somewhat reliable** would be my description of choice.

Comment: See options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20617997