# How to update python script/application remotely

Tags: python, server, remote-access, auto-update

I'm trying to develop a windows gui app with python and i will distribute that later. I don't know how to set the app for some future releasing updates or bug fix from a server/remotely. How can I handle this problem? Can I add some auto-update future to app? What should write for that in my code and what framework or library should I use? 
Do pyinstaller/ inno setup have some futures for this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you use github for this? https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remotely update Python applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932389/how-to-remotely-update-python-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

1. You can use a version control service like github to version control your code.
2. Then checkout the repository on your windows machine.
3. Write a batch/bash script to checkout the latest version of your code and restart the app.
4. Then use the Windows task scheduler to periodically run this script.