# Wait until a certain process (knowing the "pid") end

Tags: python, linux, process, wait, pid

I have this:

```
def get_process():
    pids = []
    process = None
    for i in os.listdir('/proc'):
        if i.isdigit():
            pids.append(i)

    for pid in pids:
        proc = open(os.path.join('/proc', pid, 'cmdline'), 'r').readline()
        if proc == "Something":
            process = pid

    return process          

def is_running(pid):
    return os.path.exists("/proc/%s" % str(pid))
```

Then i do this:

```
process = get_process()
if process == None:
    #do something
else:
    #Wait until the process end
    while is_running(process):
        pass
```

I think this is not the best way to wait for the process to terminate, there must be some function wait or something, but i can't find it.

Disclaimer: The process is not a child process

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not really a Python programmer, but apparently Python does have [`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/os-process.html#l2h-2774).  That should consume less CPU time and provide a much faster response than, say, trying to kill the process at quarter-second intervals.

---

**Addendum:** As Niko points out, `os.waitpid()` may not work if the process is not a child of the current process.  In that case, using `os.kill(pid, 0)` may indeed be the best solution.  Note that, in general, there are three likely outcomes of calling `os.kill()` on a process:

1. If the process exists and belongs to you, the call succeeds.
2. If the process exists but belong to another user, it throws an `OSError` with the `errno` attribute set to [`errno.EPERM`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#errno.EPERM).
3. If the process does not exist, it throws an `OSError` with the `errno` attribute set to [`errno.ESRCH`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#errno.ESRCH).

Thus, to reliably check whether a process exists, you should do something like

```
def is_running(pid):        
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno == errno.ESRCH:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: That only works for a child process. It would be great if this works for any process.

Comment: This won't work on Windows - the kill signal unconditionally kills the process sent the signal ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill)).

Answer (score 2):

Since that method would only work on linux, for linux/osx support, you could do:

```
import time
import os

def is_running(pid):
    stat = os.system("ps -p %s &> /dev/null" % pid)
    return stat == 0

pid = 64463

while is_running(pid):
    time.sleep(.25)
```

**Edit** - Per tMc's comment about excessive processes

Referencing:  [How to check if there exists a process with a given pid in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/check-if-pid-is-not-in-use-in-python/568285#568285)

Wouldn't this use less resources (I havent tested), than listing on the filesystem and opening FDs to all the results?

```
import time
import os

def is_running(pid):        
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError:
        return False

    return True

pid = 64463

while is_running(pid):
    time.sleep(.25)
```

Comment: this will spawn a subshell, which will spawn a process for the ps command,  creating 8 processes a second.

Comment: What if the call to os.system were replaced with the method he uses [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/check-if-pid-is-not-in-use-in-python/568285#568285) ?

Comment: Thats better than stating /proc/<pid> IMHO.

Comment: It seems a better idea, i'll use it

Comment: Should I also write `is_running()` inside a `try/except`?

Comment: @alper no that isn't necessary. The kill is the one to likely raise if the pid is gone. The running check should not be exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

`import time`, then use `time.sleep(#)`:

```
import time
process = get_process()
if process == None:
    #do something
else:
    #Wait until the process end
    while is_running(process):
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

I also have that exact same function in several of my scrips to read through `/proc/#/cmdline` to check for a PID.

Comment: This prevents the program uses 100% of one of the cores of my cpu, i hadnt really noticed that :P but anyway there should be some function, however I think this solution isn't so bad.

Comment: With threading you could do somewhat better, but it gets really overcomplicated for this simple of a task and threads have expensive overhead.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and reliable way of doing this with Python is by getting a list of PIDs with psutil, and then checking if your PID is in that list of running PIDs:

```
import psutil

def check_pid(pid):

    if int(pid) in psutil.pids(): ## Check list of PIDs
        return True ## Running
    else:
        return False ## Not Running
```

To use it, just run it in a simple while loop.

```
pid = 1000
running = True

while running == True:
    running = check_pid(int(pid))
    (Do stuff *until* PID ends)

(Do stuff *after* PID ends)
```

---

Or you could just put all that into one function...

```
def pause_while_running(pid):

    running = True

    while running:
        if int(pid) not in psutil.pids():
            running = False
        time.sleep(5)
```

and use like

```
pause_while_running(pid)
(do stuff after PID ended)
```