# Python subprocess script keeps running after it is done

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, subprocess

In one of my Django views, I am calling a python script and getting its pid with:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['python', 'script.py'])
mypid = p.pid
```

When trying to find out if the process still is running from another page, I use the following function on `mypid` (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/how-to-check-if-there-exists-a-process-with-a-given-pid)):

```
def doesProcessExist(pid):
    if pid < 0:
        return False
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError, e:
        return e.errno == errno.EPERM
    else:
        return True
```

No matter how long I wait, **the process still shows up as running**. The only thing that stops it, is if I spawn a new python script process with Popen. **Is there anyway I can fix this**? I am not sure if this is caused by Django not closing python properly after the script is finished or something else. In Ubuntu's process status manager, the process shows up as `[python] <defunct>`.

--

The problem is true for all `script.py` I have tried. I am currently using one as simple as:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is a zombie process. It doesn't keep running. It can't. It is dead. The only thing that is left is some info that allows for related processes to retrieve its status.

To find out whether a subprocess is alive without blocking, call `p.poll()`. If it returns `None` then the process is still alive, otherwise you can safely forget about it (it is already reaped by `.poll()`).

`subprocess` module calls `_cleanup()` function that reaps zombie processes inside [`Popen()` constructor](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l647). So normally your script won't create many zombie processes anyway.

To see a list of zombie processes:

```
import os
#NOTE: don't use Popen() here
print os.popen(r"ps aux | grep Z | grep -v grep").read(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Really, what you're doing is wrong. When you use a high-level wrapper like a `subprocess.Popen`, you need to manage the process through that object. Just having the PID elsewhere isn't enough to manage it.

If you insist on dealing in PIDs instead of `Popen` objects, then you should use the low-level APIs in `os`.

Fortunately, you're not doing anything complicated, like creating pipes to talk to the child process. So, you can just launch it with your favorite [`spawn`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.spawnl) variant, then wait for it with [`waitpid`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.waitpid) or one of its variants.

---

I'm assuming you're doing this all in a single-process web server. If you're using a forking web server, where the other page could be in a different process, even using PIDs won't work. The parent process has to reap the child, not some other arbitrary process. If you want to make that work, you'll have to make things more complicated, and you're really going to have to learn about the Unix process model before anyone can explain it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Processes in Unix stick around until the parent waits for them. calling wait on the object returned by thepopen  will wait for the process to be done and will wait for it so it goes away.  Until you do that it will exist as a [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)  See [this message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-December/026748.html) for info on getting the process to go away in the background while your web server runs without waiting for it in a foreground thread/view.

So, let's say that you do

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
```

At some point you need to call
    p.wait()

Comment: What you need to call is `wait`, not `close`. Also, you need to call it on the `Popen` process object, not on any pipe(s) you got (which is good, because in this case he doesn't _have_ any pipes.)

Comment: @aba Thanks; updated.Was confusing C's pclose with subprocess.Popen

Comment: The thing is that I am waiting for the process in another page than where it was created, so I do not have the subprocess to run either wait() or communicate() on, but only the pid of the subprocess.