# How to check process have running in python (in linux)?

Tags: python

I am trying to check if the process is running based on process name (test.py) ,  then exit

```
l = commands.getstatusoutput("ps aux |grep 'python2.7'| grep      
'test.py' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l")

if int(l[1]) == 1:
    pid = commands.getstatusoutput("ps -ef |grep 'python2.7'|  grep 'test.py ' |awk '{print $2}'")
    print "the process 'test.py ' have running ,the pid is :"+str(pid[1])
    sys.exit(0)

else:
   print "not running"
```

Output:

```
georgetovrea@dev:/test$ python2.7  test.py 
the process 'test.py ' have running ,the pid is :26517
26542
```

then I try to check

```
 $ ps aux | grep agg_test
 georgetovrea 25181  0.0  0.0  10944   932 pts/9    S+   23:26   0:00 grep --color=auto test
```

the process is not running, I want to check if the process( test.py) have running ,then exit ,
but it's always print the process is running ,

How do I check the process have running ?  Any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the command you're running from within Python reporting anything different versus if you just run that command in the shell?

Comment: Nick, when run the test.py,Output is  " the process 'test.py ' have running ,the pid is :26517
26542"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/how-to-check-if-there-exists-a-process-with-a-given-pid-in-python).

Answer (score -1):

The program runs fine for me.
I guess you are running the program with `python` instead of `python2.7` specifically.

(a) Try using `python` instead of `python2.7` in your grep statement,then the culprit is indeed your usage of python.

(b) Change it back to `python2.7` and run your program with full path to python2.7

The program:

```
import commands
import sys

l = commands.getstatusoutput("ps aux |grep 'python2.7'| grep 'test.py' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l")

print(l)
if int(l[1]) == 1:
    pid = commands.getstatusoutput("ps -ef |grep 'python2.7'|  grep 'test.py ' |awk '{print $2}'")
    print "the process 'test.py ' have running ,the pid is :"+str(pid[1])
    sys.exit(0)

else:
   print "not running"
```

Output:

```
dhruv@dhruvpathak:/tmp$ /usr/bin/python2.7  test.py 

(0, '1')

the process 'test.py ' have running ,the pid is :15620
```

Comment: DhruvPathak , I am running the program with python2.7 , the process is not running but running the program to check and get the message "get the process 'test.py' have running ,the pid is :28373 , "

Comment: What is the name of your python file ?