# Robot Framework: How to use 'Is Process Running' keyword on a python function

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to use some of the Process Library keywords that require the 'handle' as an arguement.
E.g.: Is Process Running, Process Should Be Running

According to the documentation, "The handle can be the identifier returned by Start Process or an alias explicitly given to Start Process or Run Process."  This is fine if you want to run a python script.

However, I want to use the 'Is Process Running' keyword on a process started by a using a python function in a keyword. E.g.:

```
Monitor Ipsec
    IsIpsecRunning
```

Where IsIpsecRunning is a python function. Any hints how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the documentation says,  you must pass it an identifier from `Start Process` or `Run Process`. You can't use it for arbitrary python functions or processes.

Instead, you'll have to modify your `IsIpsecRunning` function to scan a list of running processes to see if the one you are interested is listed. Or, if it's the function that started some other process, it can save off the process id in a variable which you can [pass to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/568285/7432) to determine if the process is running.