# How to check is subprocess of suborocess has finished Python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

i'm writing a simple gui script A which is calling another script B in it. Scrip B has subprocess in it which takes some time. I would like to print something like "processing..." in one of the labels on that gui and that print should be there until subprocess from script B is finished. How i can do that?

edit:

If i should have to listen for termination of subprocess of script A from script A i would simply name that process (i.e p) and check its p.poll(). Since that subprocess is product of antorher script B, i thought if i could name that process and import that script B in script A and then check for p.poll. But i faced another problem, i couldn't import script B to A. The steps i was doing were from:
[Importing variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file)
Every time i got message that there is no such file. Fortunately at the end i found another way around to achieve what i wanted.

Comment: This is a very generic question, that is hard to answer. You will find your answer using a tutorial much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I would split this task into two stages:

1. [get subprocess PID](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).
2. [check whether PID is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/how-to-check-if-there-exists-a-process-with-a-given-pid-in-python).